# git-lfs gives "Error: unknown command “post-merge” for “git-lfs”"?

Tags: git, git-lfs

When doing a git pull or fetch/rebase on our server, git prints this *warning*:

```
Error: unknown command “post-merge” for “git-lfs”
```

Interestingly enough, things still work (so git-lfs does its job and fetches large files as expected).

Some online resources suggest that the .git/hooks/commit/post-merge file is at fault, but I checked: all hook files are the same when comparing them to other repos (on my local machine).

So how could this be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our case, the reason was simply an *outdated* version of git-lfs.

Our git/gerrit server, and its infrastructure was updated recently.

Now we pushed `git-lfs` to the latest version available (2.51 for our version of Redhat Linux) and the message is gone.

( I was really surprised to learn that the previous version of git-lfs was showing up as 1.1 )